# How to start loop over after inputBox validation?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to start the loop over if a non numeric value is entered for student grade. The application is supposed to have 3 student names and grades input but my program currently just proceeds to the next student input when error occurs. I'm currently using parallel array method for the inputbox and try catch statements for input valdation.

```
Public Class Form2
'Class level variable declaration
Dim dblAverage As Double
Dim studentGrade As Char
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    lstOutput.Items.Clear()
    Const intMAX_ROW As Integer = 2 'Highest Row subscript
    Const intMAX_COL As Integer = 2 'Highest Column subscript
    Dim intRow, intCol As Integer 'Row and column loop counter

    Dim strName(intMAX_ROW) As String 'Name Array initilization 

    Dim intMarks(intMAX_ROW, intMAX_COL) As String 'Marks Array initialization 

    Dim intTotal As Integer

    'Sum Name array through rows
    For intRow = 0 To intMAX_ROW

        strName(intRow) = InputBox("Enter Student name")

            lstOutput.Items.Add("Test Scores for: " & strName(intRow))

        'Error handling using try catch expression
        Try

            'Initialize accumulator
            intTotal = 0
            'Enter and sum Marks Column within the same row
            For intCol = 0 To intMAX_COL

                intMarks(intRow, intCol) = InputBox("Enter the score for test " & (intCol + 1))

                If intMarks(intRow, intCol) >= 0 And intMarks(intRow, intCol) <= 100 Then

                    intTotal += intMarks(intRow, intCol)
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Enter Marks must be between 0-100")
                End If

                lstOutput.Items.Add(intMarks(intRow, intCol))

            Next
            


            'To calculate average
            dblAverage = intTotal / (intMAX_COL + 1)
            'To Display
            lstOutput.Items.Add("The total test scores for " & strName(intRow) & " is " & intTotal.ToString())
            lstOutput.Items.Add("Results: ")
            lstOutput.Items.Add(strName(intRow) & "   Average: " & Math.Round(dblAverage) & "   Grade: " & Grades())
            lstOutput.Items.Add("")
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Score must be numeric between 0-100")
        End Try

    Next

End Sub

'Grade Condition Function
Function Grades()
    If dblAverage >= 90 And dblAverage <= 100 Then
        studentGrade = "A"
    ElseIf dblAverage >= 80 And dblAverage <= 89 Then
        studentGrade = "B"
    ElseIf dblAverage >= 70 And dblAverage <= 79 Then
        studentGrade = "C"
    ElseIf dblAverage >= 60 And dblAverage <= 69 Then
        studentGrade = "D"
    Else
        studentGrade = "F"
    End If

    Return studentGrade
End Function

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Firstly, what do you mean by "start the loop over"? That literally suggests discarding any input you have received and starting again from scratch. That seems rather inefficient. Maybe you mean repeating the current iteration, but that is also inefficient. Why not just keep prompting the user for the current value until they give you something valid? That would mean putting the `InputBox` call inside a `Do...Loop While` loop. Just keep prompting them until they give you something.

Answer (score 0):

Try/Catch is meant for unexpected errors that are out of your control. Validation of user input is within your control and incorrect user input is definitely expected.

Your application begs for a `Class` to store student's name and grade information. The use of a class makes the code much more readable.

```
Public Class StudentGrades
    Public Property StudentName As String
    Public Property TestScores As New List(Of Integer)
    Public Property DisplayScores As String
    Public Property Average As Double
    Public Property Grade As String

    Public Sub New(Name As String)
        StudentName = Name
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetAverage()
        'Avoid division by zero
        If TestScores.Count > 0 Then
            Average = TestScores.Sum / TestScores.Count
        Else
            Average = 0
        End If
        SetGrade()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetGrade()
        Select Case Average
            Case 90 To 101
                Grade = "A"
            Case 80 To 90
                Grade = "B"
            Case 70 To 80
                Grade = "C"
            Case 60 To 70
                Grade = "D"
            Case Else
                Grade = "F"
        End Select
        SetDisplayScores()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetDisplayScores()
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For Each i In TestScores
            sb.Append(i.ToString & ",")
        Next
        'Trim the final comma from the string
        DisplayScores = sb.ToString.Trim(","c)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The class begins with the properties. `StudentName` is a single String. Since there can be more than one test score we use a `List(Of T)` to hold the scores. User input in the form sets `StudentName` and fills the score list. `DisplayScores` is a single string composed of the scores in the list. The `DataGridView` needs this to display the scores.

Next is the constructor for the class. The `Sub New` creates an instance of the class. This constructor requires a string input which sets the `StudentName` property.

We call `SetAverage` from the form which in turn calls `SetGrade` which calls `SetDisplayScores`. So, all the properties are set.

In the form, create a list of `StudentGrades`  to hold each student and all their data. This is at `Form` level so it can be seen by all methods on the form and exits as long as the form does.

In `Button1`, get the user input for the name, validate, and create a new  `StudentGrades` passing the name entered by the user. Next we loop getting the user input for scores validating as we go by calling the `ValidateScore` method. Once validated the score is added to the list of scores for `StudentGrades` instance (`stu`) created earlier in the procedure.

When the user responds No to the message box, call the `SetAverage` method on `stu` (the current instance of the class) which will set the remaining properties of `StudentGrades`. Lastly, add `stu` to the form level `StuList`.

Finally, in Button3, set the `DataSouce` property of a `DataGridView` to `StuList` and there is all the data entered by the user.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim StuName = InputBox("Enter Student name")
    'Loop until a name is entered.
    Do While String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StuName)
        StuName = InputBox("You must enter a name before recording grades")
    Loop
    Dim stu As New StudentGrades(StuName)
    Dim MBResult As DialogResult
    'Loop until user is done entering scores for this student.
    Do
        Dim strScore = InputBox($"Enter the score for test {stu.StudentName}")
        If Not ValidateScore(strScore) Then
            'Loop until user enters a valid score.
            Do
                strScore = InputBox("You must enter a number between 0 and 100")
            Loop Until ValidateScore(strScore)
        End If
        stu.TestScores.Add(CInt(strScore))
        MBResult = MessageBox.Show($"Add another score for {StuName}?", "Add Another?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    Loop Until MBResult = DialogResult.No
    stu.SetAverage()
    StuList.Add(stu)
End Sub

Private Function ValidateScore(strScore As String) As Boolean
    Dim score As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(strScore, score) AndAlso score >= 0 AndAlso score <= 100 Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    DataGridView1.DataSource = StuList
End Sub
```